# Ctrl+C is not working a lot of times when editing a question or answering a question

Tags: bug, status-norepro, keyboard-shortcuts

When editing an answer, sometimes I need to copy some characters from the question or my editing answer. But it happens a lot of times that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy is not working, and I have to do it twice or more. But it doesn't appear in the other websites. Is this a known problem, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Please give us a screenshot/video/some example of this. I haven't seen this, but for the team to find anything that could be wrong, they need more information. And it's possible that it's due to your browser or computer...

Comment: @hichris123 - or keyboard.

Comment: we are not hooking that shortcut, there must be something wrong with your keyboard

Answer (score 10):

Carefully examine your keyboard. If it resembles this...

[image]

...then you may need a new keyboard.

Comment: Perfect answer...

Comment: :] . but It doesn't appear on other website.

Comment: @johnMa - As Ctrl+C is a feature implemented by the OS (in nearly all textbox-related scenarios), it is not something that SO could be responsible for. Have you [tried rebooting](http://thedoghousediaries.com/4822)?

Comment: @JDB , hmm, seems that this is a bad question.

Comment: @johnMa it's just... not a thing SE would have much to do with. They don't have a script that makes CTRL+C not work half the time for a joke, or anything like that. CTRL+C should just work here.